# TensorFlow same code with different results in colab and local

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


def get_uncompiled_model():
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="predictions")(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

    
class CategoricalTruePositives(keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name="categorical_true_positives", **kwargs):
        super(CategoricalTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name="ctp", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), shape=(-1, 1))
        values = tf.cast(y_true, "int32") == tf.cast(y_pred, "int32")
        values = tf.cast(values, "float32")
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, "float32")
            values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.true_positives.assign(0.0)


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype("float32") / 255
y_train = y_train.astype("float32")
y_test = y_test.astype("float32")


model = get_uncompiled_model()
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[CategoricalTruePositives(), "acc"]
)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=3)
```

```sh
# result in colab
# Python 3.7.10
# tf.__version__ 2.4.1, No GPU/TPU
Epoch 1/3
600/600 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5864 - categorical_true_positives: 26493.0133 - acc: 0.8370
Epoch 2/3
600/600 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1644 - categorical_true_positives: 28702.1930 - acc: 0.9530
Epoch 3/3
600/600 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1141 - categorical_true_positives: 29076.3261 - acc: 0.9656

# result in local
# Win 10 conda, Python 3.8.8
# tf.__version__ 2.4.1, No GPU
# 60000 * 0.9014 = 54084.0 ≈ 54085.0000
# 60000 * 0.9531 = 57186.0 ≈ 57189.0000
# 60000 * 0.9651 = 57906.0 ≈ 57909.0000
Epoch 1/3
600/600 [==============================] - 0s 794us/step - loss: 0.3487 - categorical_true_positives: 54085.0000 - acc: 0.9014
Epoch 2/3
600/600 [==============================] - 0s 792us/step - loss: 0.1575 - categorical_true_positives: 57189.0000 - acc: 0.9531
Epoch 3/3
600/600 [==============================] - 0s 753us/step - loss: 0.1158 - categorical_true_positives: 57909.0000 - acc: 0.9651
```

I can't tell which is right, the colab result is the same as the [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#custom_metrics), but the local result is as I expected. I am confused in two points:

1. the categorical_true_positives of colab is almost half of local;
2. the categorical_true_positives of colab has decimals while local has not.

Comment: That's normal. The weights are initialized randomly each time you run the above code.

Comment: @M.Innat I have ran this code several times both in colab and local, all behave like what I describe. self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name="ctp", initializer="zeros")

Comment: do you run it with the same Python version ? Do you use GPU or TPU on Colab?

Comment: @furas I have updated these information.

Comment: To add to @M.Innat's comment, if you try seeding your experiment (torch.manual_seed(1) or some other integer), you should see that the experiments match, see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.manual_seed.html

Comment: @jhso I try with `tf.random.set_seed(1)` and no difference. I don't think it's caused by random seed, the gap of categorical_true_positives between colab and local is huge, and categorical_true_positives in colab is decimal while in local is actually integer.

Comment: oops... yes tf not torch! Your accuracy metrics are very similar which is making me think that there's something up with your dataset. Have you checked it's ordered the same, the same size, and the labels are all correct etc?